# Checking it see if a file exists in a script

Tags: bash, scripts

So I have a filename bobv1.txt, and I don't want to manually check to see if bobv2.txt is on the site. On the site bobv1.txt will be replaced by bobv2.txt. I have downloaded the the html page and determined the full download path of bobvX.txt and I know were the file is in my file system. How can I tell if the file is already on my file system? I need this to work for all subsequent versions.

Comment: What kind of script are you creating? A bash script?

Comment: Just use this [file test operator](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/fto.html), 1 if exist, 0 if not. `[ -f <filename> ] && echo "1" || echo "0"`

Answer (score 4):

If you need a shell script then you can use this:

```
#!/bin/bash
file="$1"

if [ -f "$file" ]; then
    echo "File $file exists."
else
    echo "File $file does not exist."
fi
```

You can run it like this:

```
bash test.sh /tmp/bobv2.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

There's plenty of ways to perform a check on whether or not a file exists.

- use `test` command ( aka `[` ) to do `[ -f /path/to/file.txt ]`
- use redirection to attempt to open file ( note that this isn't effective if you lack permissions to read the said file)

  ```
  $ bash -c 'if < /bin/echo ;then echo "exists" ; else echo "does not exist" ; fi'                                                                                       
  exists
  $ bash -c 'if < /bin/noexist ;then echo "exists" ; else echo "does not exist" ; fi'                                                                                    
  $ bash: /bin/noexist: No such file or directory
  does not exist
  ```

  or with silencing the error message:

  ```
  $ 2>/dev/null < /etc/noexist || echo "nope"                                                                                                                            
  nope
  ```
- use external program such as `stat`

  ```
  $ if ! stat /etc/noexist 2> /dev/null; then echo "doesn't exist"; fi                                                                                                   
  doesn't exist
  ```

  or `find` command:

  ```
  $ find /etc/passwd
  /etc/passwd

  $ find /etc/noexist
  find: ‘/etc/noexist’: No such file or directory
  ```

Comment: Redirection is not an effective test, since it can fail for lack of read permissions (`[ -r file ]` vs `[ -e file ]`).

Comment: @muru good point , I'll mention that