# Execute script only once per day

Tags: bash, ubuntu-mate

I am trying to check if a certain script (Backup_18_04.sh) has been run today.

I only want it run once per day.

I found this, but it does not work.

I can not tell what it is checking for?

```
today=`/bin/date -d today '+%m-%d-%Y_%I:%M-%p'`

if [ -f /media/storagedrive/Ubuntu_Mate_18.04/$today ]
then
   echo It exists
else
   echo It does not exist
fi
```

Comment: I made the edits.

Comment: How do you have the script set up to run daily? If you're using a cron, you can check logs: https://askubuntu.com/q/56683

Comment: It's [Checking to see if a file exists in a script](https://askubuntu.com/questions/835310/checking-it-see-if-a-file-exists-in-a-script)